# Generate chart from google visualization chart and convert in to image file with node JS?

Tags: node.js, centos, google-visualization

Is it possible to run google chart with node JS? 
My goal is to generate a graph from google chart and convert the chart to image file and upload it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the google visualization `getImageURI()` method which returns the chart as a base64 string -> `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAH&SDF...`  etc :

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');</script>
```

...

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var base64 = chart.getImageURI();
    socket.emit('chart', { file: 'test.png', base64: base64 });
});
```

serverside :

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
   socket.on('chart', function(data) {
      require("fs").writeFile(data.file, data.base64, 'base64', function(err) {
         console.log(err);
      })
   })
})
```

Comment: apology david I forgot to say in my question that I only need to use cron job and not to visit the page.
I need to create image file from the chart every week to be use in weekly sending of report.

Comment: How can it be possible to generate the image without visiting the page?

Comment: @Gige, OK - the GV API is entirely clientside so either way you have to render the chart in a browser and send the imagedata to the server to save.  You could let the cronjob invoke a browser that opens a certain page ..?

Comment: How about using of zombieJS?  It's a headless browser that can emulate the browser. Do you think it will work?

Comment: @Gige, dont know zombieJS, but it does not seem to be able to do that.  See http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html ...Imagine you have a "secret" URL producing the chart, and a cronjob taking a screen capture produced by phantomJS. Just a suggestion, have not tried it myself.

Comment: google.visualization is not recognized by node. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this now with [Google Charts Node](https://github.com/typpo/google-charts-node), which uses Puppeteer to headlessly render the Google Chart.

Here's an example:

```js
const GoogleChartsNode = require('google-charts-node');

function drawChart() {
  // Set up your chart here, just like in the browser
  // ...

  const chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(container);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

// Render the chart to image
const image = await GoogleChartsNode.render(drawChart, {
  width: 400,
  height: 300,
});
```